# Subtract two numbers with same key in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have 2 files of the form

**File 1**:

key1 value1

key2 value2

...

**File 2**:

key1 value3

key2 value4

...

I would like to produce a reduce output of the form

key1 (value1-value3)/value1

key2 (value2-value4)/value2

I have the map write the key and the value is prepended with a character telling it is
coming from file1 or file2, but not sure how to write the reduce stage

My map method is

```
public void map(LongWritable key,Text val,Context context) throws IOException,     InterruptedException
    {
        Text outputKey = new Text();
        Text outputValue = new Text();
        outputKey.set(key.toString());
        if ("A")
        {               
            outputValue.set("A,"+val);
        }
        else
        {
            outputValue.set("B," + val);
        }
        context.write(outputKey,  outputValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple enough since you already tagged it, although a bit confusing to start. I assume that emitted values are like `A23`(for file1) & `B139`(for file2).  Snippet :

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    int diff = 0;
    int denominator = 1;
    for (Text val : values) {
        if (val.toString().startsWith("A")) {
            denominator = Integer.parseInt(val.toString().substring(1));
            diff += denominator;
        } else if (val.toString().startsWith("B")) {
            diff -= Integer.parseInt(val.toString().substring(1));
        } else {
            // This block shouldn't be reached unless malformed values are emitted
            // Throw an exception or log it
        }
    }
    diff /= denominator;
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(diff));
}
```

Hope this will help. But I think your approach will fail badly when `key1` and `key2` are equal.

**UPDATE**
The `map` should be like the following to work with the above reducer :

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text val, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
        String[] keyVal = val.toString().split("\\s+");
        Text outputKey = new Text(keyVal[0]);
        Text outputValue = new Text();
        outputKey.set(key.toString());
        if ("fileA".equals(fileName)) {
            outputValue.set("A" + keyVal[1]);
        } else {
            outputValue.set("B" + keyVal[1]);
        }
        context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This was my first try by somehow it doesnt seem to work. Every time reduce is called values is a single object instead of the two I would expect (one from each file for the same key). I added my map method maybe it is incorrect. The case key1=key2 will never happen in this particular example.

Comment: It won't even compile, tagging is on Pluto ;-). I'll update the question itself, don't want to edit the answer at all. You may change key types to `InWritable` later on, but do add a `keyVal`.length check to get rid of AOBException. Have a look now.

Comment: They rejected my edit to the question. So I post it here. I assumed the file names are FileA & FileB.

Answer (score 0):

I have found using NamedVector very helpful in such circumstances. This provides an identification for the value so that you can perform required operations on the values based on the "name".